# Firebird 2.5 TRIM(TRAILING FROM FIELD) very slow on UTF8

Tags: firebird, trim

First of all, my server version, so I don't forget it: WI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5

I have two databases on the same server. They share the same structure and (almost) same data, and differ only on the charset. In fact, *database 1* is an old ISO8859_1 database that has been migrated to an UTF8 database, *database 2*. So:

- Database 1: ISO8859_1. Relevant field is `COD Char(21) NOT NULL`
- Database 2: UTF8 Collation UNICODE_CI_AI. Relevant field is `COD Char(21) NOT NULL COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI`

Both share the same ODS version (11.2) and dialect (3).

I have a few `WHERE TRIM(TRAILING FROM field) like '%something'`. Problem is that this query executes virtually instantly in database 1, but is taking about a minute to complete in database 2 (I have both on the same server), in a table with about 50k records. In the meantime the fbserver process shows 25% cpu usage (1 out of the 4 cores). CPU_AFFINITY is set to use 2 cores (I guess not on the same query). Field is indexed, but PLAN is natural in **both** databases.

Running `SELECT TRIM(TRAILING FROM field) FROM table` in both databases shows the same performance issues in database 2 (but not in 1), so I really believe it must have to do with charset and the trim function.

If anyone knows how to workaround this issue, I'd be grateful. Any tips on understanding why this is happening is also very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the field type?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I always forget something. It's `Char(21)`. I've included this on the question.

Comment: Is the difference in performance also noticable when you don't trim?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Noticeable to a human, no. But `Total execution time` on FlameRobin shows ~0.095 vs ~0.075s (I executed a few times... these are rough averages). Both are indexed queries, in this case.

Comment: Apparently, string operations on Firebird are in general much slower with UTF8 than it is with ISO8859_1. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%1'` also shows a significant performance difference (with the same 1 core hog): 35s vs 0.250s to fetch 75 records.

Comment: Performance problem is with the collation. I tried the `UCS_BASIC` and `UNICODE` and both have no performance problems. Wish I knew this a week ago (before the whole migration process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug in Firebird 2.5.2 that makes selects on UNICODE_CI_AI fields extremely slow. This has been corrected in the upcoming 2.5.3 version.

Here is the corresponding item in the Firebird bug tracker: [CORE-4125](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-4125)

So the workaround is to use a Firebird 2.5.3 snapshot or wait until 2.5.3 will be released. According to the [Roadmap](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/roadmap/) this should happen in Q1/2014.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Interesting, thanks... I'm not feeling very adventurous lately, so I will probably wait for the official release. In the meantime, I've already changed all collations in the database and this solved performance issues. Btw, very nice website, taught me a lot about charsets... really helpful.